# Application metrics in dotcloud doesn't show any activity

Tags: dotcloud

The "Application metrics" page of my Dotcloud applicaton doesn't show any activity during the last 24h. There should be something as I know that the application has been accessed.

This feature was working fine one or two weeks ago.

My application is a java application built with Play! framework

It is a known issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you did anything wrong; I would recommend that you contact [dotCloud's support](http://support.dotcloud.com/).